# gradle:issues with OSGI-INF folder for OSGI/SCR plugins

Tags: gradle, osgi, osgi-bundle

When I am trying to generate the OSGI-bundle having OSGI-INF folder information,I am unable to get that folder created using apply plugin:'scr' in my gradle build file.Any pointers please?

I am using Java 1.8.Task where it is failing is `task ':processScrAnnotations'`.

I am getting the below exception which is not giving useful messaging:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.felix.scrplugin.helper.ClassScanner.processClass(ClassScanner.java:172)
        at org.apache.felix.scrplugin.helper.ClassScanner.scanSources(ClassScanner.java:143)
        at org.apache.felix.scrplugin.SCRDescriptorGenerator.execute(SCRDescriptorGenerator.java:149)
        at org.apache.felix.scrplugin.ant.SCRDescriptorTask.execute(SCRDescriptorTask.java:129)
        at org.apache.felix.scrplugin.ant.SCRDescriptorTask$execute.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
        at com.twcable.gradle.scr.ScrPlugin.configureAction(ScrPlugin.groovy:77)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:382)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1015)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:806)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:444)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:369)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1015)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at com.twcable.gradle.scr.ScrPlugin$_addScrTask_closure1_closure4.doCall(ScrPlugin.groovy:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:292)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1015)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:439)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:554)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:535)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 68 more
```

Comment: What Gradle plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gradle plugin you are using is itself using an older version of ASM that does not understand Java 8 class files. You need the gradle plugin to be updated by the authors to use a more recent version of ASM which does understand Java 8 class files.